space in a command line argument in java
When the sentences written under single quote is added as one argument in java?
like - 'i am a good boy'
this is also java is considering as single argument
like " i am a good boy"
so is it "double quote argument is same" == 'single quote to provide space in java'
single quote and double quote is same in command line argument in JAVA for providing space

is there actually a question in here?

Depends on how you are issuing the java command. Is it from a terminal or command prompt? Is it from a script?

I think he wanna know if he can use either of them, single or double quoted arguments. Anyhow, this is more an OS question how the current CLI handles enquoted arguments. In the end, all arguments are provided as an Array String[] args.

Assuming you are talking about e.g. writing:
java -jar myapp.jar arg1 arg2 "this is arg 3"

In that case, you misunderstand how all of this stuff works. You wrote:

as one argument in java?

That's just wrong. Java has nothing to do with this. That big black boxy thing you type commands into is not your OS. It's an application - it's cmd.exe on windows, or some terminal tool on any other OS. You're typing commands into that tool, for example, you're sending those commands to /bin/bash which is a shell application. That tool interprets what you wrote.
The OS has an API so that one application can launch another application. it is not text based - you do not tell the OS:
java -jar myapp.jar arg1 arg2 "this is arg 3"

Instead, it's more like a method call. You do the equivalent of:
osSystem.launchApplication(
  location: "/bin/java",
  env: [A whole bunch of environment variables here],
  arguments: [
    arg1
    arg2
    this is arg 3
  ],
  standard in: [A descriptor of a source of bytes],
  standard out: [A descriptor of a processor of bytes],
  standard err: [A descriptor of a processor of bytes],
)

Where bash uses the PATH variable (again, not an OS thing, that's your terminal tool that knows what a PATH is; the OS doesn't generally), bash hooks up the keyboard as standard in and its own screen as standard out and err, and copies all exported elements from the environment. Bash does all this. Not your OS. Or tcsh, or cmd.exe, or whatever the command line tool is.
Java exposes those arguments via String[] args and just takes them verbatim from the OS (which took them from bash), it does no quote parsing of any form on any of this. It exposes that env via System.getenv(), and System.in/out/err are where standard in/out/err end up.
So, who does the quote thing? Bash does the quote thing. You'd read the documentation of bash to learn about why ' and " are both allowed and what the differences are. And everything you learn there only applies to bash. Not to tcsh. Not to cmd.exe. Java isn't running yet, so, any idea of 'write once run anywhere' doesn't apply yet.
If instead you are talking about java's own Runtime.getRuntime().exec, all you need to know is that it's nebulous and weird and you should never use that. Instead use ProcessBuilder, and supply the whole list of arguments, never ask ProcessBuilder to untangle a whole string by quote parsing. You'll have more readable, easier to test, more flexible code - winwinwin.
